# Tomcat failed to start and generating java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException as below, once I initialized the web.xml with listener-class

Tags: sqlite, tomcat, ormlite, servletcontextlistener

Given error:

> INFO: Starting service Catalina Feb 15, 2016 2:23:09 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 Feb 15, 2016 2:23:09 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation
>   using [SHA1PRNG] took [116] milliseconds. Feb 15, 2016 2:23:09 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/storyboard]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/storyboard]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2575)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1908)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
>     ... 20 more

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>UploadImage</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.home.storyboard.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>UploadCanvas</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.home.storyboard.UploadCanvas</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UploadImage</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/uploadimage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UploadCanvas</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/uploadcanvas</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>StoryServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.home.storyboard.StoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StoryServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/StoryServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
   <description>ServletContextListener</description>
   <listener-class>com.home.storyboard.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**StartupListener**

```
package com.home.storyboard;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
import com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import com.home.storyboard.DAOdb;


public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener{
private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:testdb.db"; 

ConnectionSource connectionSource = null;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
        // create our data-source for the database
        connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(DATABASE_URL);
        DAOdb db = new DAOdb(connectionSource);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("db", db);

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
 }

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // destroy the data source which should close underlying connections

    DAOdb db = (DAOdb)sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("db");
    db.close();
 }
 }
```

**DAOdb class**

```
package com.home.storyboard;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.GenericRawResults;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;

 public class DAOdb {

// we are using the in-memory H2 database
private final ConnectionSource connectionSource;
private Dao<User, Integer> userDAO;
private Dao<Profile,Integer> profileDAO;
private Dao<Story, Integer> storyDAO;
private String lastError;

public DAOdb(ConnectionSource connectionSource){
    this.connectionSource=connectionSource;
    try{
    userDAO = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, User.class);
    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, User.class);
    profileDAO = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Profile.class);
    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Profile.class);
    storyDAO = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Story.class);
    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Story.class);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        lastError = e.getMessage().toString();
    }
}

/**
 * DAO Functions to fetch data
 */

 public void addStory(Story S) {
     try{
         storyDAO.create(S);
         lastError = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            lastError = e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }

 public List<Story> getStoriesbyUsername(String username) {
     String uname =username;
     List<Story> storyList = null;
     User user = getUserbyUsername(uname);
     Integer uid =user.getId();
     try{
        GenericRawResults<String[]> stories = storyDAO.queryRaw(
                "select count(*) from stories where userid = uid");
            // there should be 1 result
            List<String[]> results = stories.getResults();
            // the results array should have 1 value
            Integer usercount = results.size();
            // this should print the number of orders that have this account-id
            if(usercount<=0){
                lastError="'No story exists by username'+' '+ username";
              }else{
                 storyList = storyDAO.queryBuilder()
                             .where()
                             .eq(Story.USERID_FIELD_NAME, uid)
                             .query();
              }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                lastError = e.getMessage().toString();
            }

      return storyList;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too long and involved.  The important part of it is this caused by exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource at ...

For some reason your application does not have the `ConnectionSource` class.  Maybe you are not including both the ORMLite JDBC as well as core jar?  Make sure to follow the [getting started documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started) which talks about this:

> Users that are connecting to SQL databases via JDBC connections will need to download the ormlite-jdbc-4.48.jar and ormlite-core-4.48.jar files. For use with Android applications, you should download the ormlite-android-4.48.jar and ormlite-core-4.48.jar files instead. For either JDBC or Android you will also need the ormlite-core release which has the ORMLite backend implementations.

If you are using a war, find the jar location and make sure both ORMLite jars are there.  If you already have the core in your application then I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Class not found exception was resolved after uploading Ormlite core and Ormlite jdbc jars in the lib/ext folder of Java JRE. This is not the optimum solution. But for now it works for me.